# Pyspark get max value exclude NaN

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, nan

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1.0,100.0, float('nan')), (float('nan'),100.0, 2.0)], ("a", "b"))
df.select(F.max(df.a)).show()
```

the result is :

```
+------+
|max(a)|
+------+
|   NaN|
+------+
```

I didn't want the NaN,how can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do

```
df.na.fill(0)
```

before you apply your `max` filter

Comment: If max is a negative number, you will have a problem.